# c++ return pointer vs. return a local object with std::move

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have to create a function which creates a set of characters for me. I am not sure which of the following approaches I should prefer. 
As far as I understood I should not use createSet1 because if something goes wrong before returning s it will leak.

```
set<char>* createSet1(){
    set<char>* s = new set<char>;
    //does something
    return s;
}

set<char> createSet2(){
    set<char> s;
    //does something
    return std::move(s);
}

unique_ptr<set<char>> createSet3(){
    unique_ptr<set<char>> s(new set<char>);
    //does something
    return s;
}
```

I would be happy if someone could explain which one I should prefer and why.

Comment: no need to "say" `return std::move(...)`, since the returned value is implicitely a rvalue. You actually got that right in the `unique_ptr` case (did you notice `unique_ptr` is move-only?)

Comment: Ah, alright, I thought std::move is necessary if it is not one of those "clever" pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr). Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the above:

```
std::set<char> createSet() {
   std::set<char> s;
   // do something
   return s;
}
```

There is no reason to dynamically allocate the set, RVO will kick in and remove the copy for you, without having to pay the cost of the extra dynamic allocation and management of that memory.

---

Now for the concrete problem of a set of characters, you might be better off not using a set at all, but rather a `std::vector` correctly sized:

```
class CharSet {
   std::vector<bool> d_data; // std::vector<bool> quirks are fine here
   void set(char ch, bool value) {
      d_data[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)] = value;
   }
public:
   CharSet() : d_data(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()+1) {}
   void set(char ch)   { set(ch,true); }
   void unset(char ch) { set(ch,false); }
   bool isset(char ch) const { 
      return d_data[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
   }
};
```

The advantage of this approach is that the higher cost you are going to pay is the dynamic allocation of the nodes in the `std::set`, and each such allocation has a cost compared to the single allocation in the case of `std::vector` (for a small enough vector). The memory of the `std::vector<bool>` is going to be roughly 32 bytes, which is comparable to a single node in the `std::set` on a 64bit architecture. You could even make it a `std::vector<char>` to avoid the quirks of `std::vector<bool>` and it would be 256 chars, which is the cost of just a few nodes in the set.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` is a container, meaning that you can return it without problems, so you can modify your first proposal to:

```
set<char> createSet1(){
    set<char> s;
    //does something with s
    return s;
}
```

Hope this helps